# Is "~の方が格上だ" a set phrase of sorts?

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

I've never come across "の方が格上" before, I'm wondering if it's a set phrase that would describe someone being "out of your league" in terms of power/strength so the implication is that one cannot hope to beat the person in question?

This is the original sentence I saw it in:

> ありゃ完全にあっちの方が格上だ

For context A tells B she was wants to get a little revenge on C (C beat her in battle some time ago), B rebukes her with "やめとけよ。ありゃ完全にあっちの方が格上だ"

Going by my assumption it would translate as "let it go. He's on a whole other level."

So is my assumption about ~の方が格上 correct?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a set phrase. The sentence can be translated in the usual fashion.

> あっちの方が格上だ

`Xの方{ほう}が` is used for comparisons (full form is `Xの方がYよりZ`), here we're just missing the implied `[お前]より` part. `あっち`= the third party (C). And `格上` is just "higher rank/status". So,

> They are/He is of a higher rank [than you].

Of course, depending on the context, "on a whole other level" may be an acceptable translation as well...

Comment: just a point of english grammar: it's "whole other" though quite a few people say "whole nother". but there isn't a "whole another".