# Trying to understand this use of 〜た方が

Tags: grammar, syntax

I am still stumped on understanding this one sentence:

> **今打った方が格段に実力はまさっています**
>
> ですが、彼の打つ手に正しい手はひとつもありません

[(source context panels)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI9oE.png)

In this case the speaker is talking about a go player who is bullying a weaker opponent by playing aggressive but meaningless moves.

I tried to translate it as:

> "He would be much stronger if he played with his real ability, but he's not playing a single correct move."

I tried to interpret 打った方 as A方がB that is described in pages like [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/what-is-%E6%96%B9-used-for-when-attached-to-a-%E3%81%9F-verb/6527#6527), but still I think I am on the wrong track.

How is 〜た方が actually being used here, and how do I make sense of this sentence, grammatically?

Related:
[方 - also read ほう when referring to a person?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/%E6%96%B9-also-read-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86-when-referring-to-a-person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 方 (ほう) refers to a person. They are clearly comparing two *players*, not two *actions*. 今打った方 means "the one who just made a move", that is, the stronger player.

Related:

- [Is "~の方が格上だ" a set phrase of sorts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49031/5010)
- [Help with translation, 綺麗事 and 奴の方](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55728/5010)
- [Use of 方 in sentence (かた or ほう?) + translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42334/5010)

Comment: Just as a clarification: when you are actually referring to a person specifically, it is always read かた. In this case, it might be better to translate it as "side," although it might sound a bit weird. 方 is only referring to a person by proxy in this case, if that makes any sense. As in, the "side" (if each "side" of the fight is a person) who just made a move.

Comment: Thank you @Kurausukun At the same time I happened to find a post that clarifies this same thing: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/%E6%96%B9-also-read-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86-when-referring-to-a-person#comment22192_11024